# Markov Chain: Calculating conditional probability

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, conditional-probability, markov-process

For this problem there are 3 states zonal flow $(R1)$, intermediate $(R2)$ and blocked regime$ (R3).$ Let $A$ denote the event that more than three consecutive days are classified as blocked
regime. Calculate the probability that more than three consecutive days are classified
as blocked starting from day n which is already blocked, $P(A|Xn = 3)$. Assume the
Markov property:

I defined the state space $S= \{{1,2,3}\}$ with$ 1$ corresponding  to $R1$, $2$ corresponding to $R2 $ and $3$ corresponding to $R3$.  I let $A =\{{(X_{n+1}, X_{n+2}, X_{n+3}) = R3} \}$  which i'm not sure is correct.
Then $P(A|X_n=3) = P(X_{n+3}, X_{n+2}=3,X_{n+1}=3 | X_n =3)$. I am not sure if i'm right at all.
Would greatly appreciate the help or reassurance

Answer (score 1):

The expression should be $\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = 3 | X_n = 3) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_{n+2} = 3 | X_{n+1} = 3) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_{n+3} = 3 | X_{n+2} = 3)$

Comment: Correct, but you've phrased it like $\mathbb P(X_{n+3}=3, X_{n+2}=3, X_{n+1}=3 \mid X_n =3)$ is wrong, and it's not.

Comment: How did you get that? What should $A$ be defined as?

Comment: @MishaLavrov So just to clarify, what i wrote is correct?

Comment: Yes; you can expand one into the other using the chain rule for conditional probability, and the Markov property. The version in this answer is the one you'd want for calculations.